# Can't run distributed imagenet inception model (connection failed)

Tags: tensorflow

I used 2 Ubuntu servers to host run the distributed tensorflow. Each server installed tensorflow 0.8.0.

I first started ps server on server1:
```
ubuntu@i-mxdcqm20:/data1T5/org_models/inception$ sudo bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \

> --job_name='ps' \
>   --task_id=0 \
>   --ps_hosts='43.254.55.221:2222' \
>   --worker_hosts='61.160.41.85:2222'
>   ```、

log shows:

`INFO:tensorflow:PS hosts are: ['43.254.55.221:2222']
INFO:tensorflow:Worker hosts are: ['61.160.41.85:2222']
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {localhost:2222}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {61.160.41.85:2222}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:202] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222`

And when I run `sudo netstat -tunlp` the server is actually listening on port 2222:

`tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      3525/python`

But when I start worker on server2 it still reports failed to connect:

`E0722 10:35:01.142377237    4045 tcp_client_posix.c:191]     failed to connect to 'ipv4:43.254.55.221:2222': timeout occurred`

I'm running the code according the readme [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/README.md) and I didn't change any code.